# CodeHS how to filter books by author?

Tags: java, database, unit-testing

**This is my task:** You’ve been given a list of books to read over the summer, but you only want to read the books by a certain author.

Write a method

public List filterBooks(List readingList, String author)
That takes a List of Books as a parameter, removes all Books from the readingList that are not written by the given author, then returns the resulting list.

You can access the author of a Book by calling book.getAuthor(). The Book class is provided for reference.

**There are two classes given...**

### Book.java

```
public class Book
{
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book(String theTitle, String theAuthor)
    {
        title = theTitle;
        author = theAuthor;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return title + " by " + author;
    }

    public boolean equals(Book other)
    {
        return title.equals(other.title) && author.equals(other.author);
    }
}
```

### Unit Test

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, String author)
{
    // Remove all Books from the readingList that are not
    // written by the given author. Return the resulting List
}
```

Im not really sure how to approach this problem... I know that it may be a lot to explain but I really need to wrap my head around this sort of logical coding... Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Removing the books from `readingList` doesn't really make sense.  1) Create a new list, such as List<Book> booksByAuthor; 2) iterate over `readingList`; 3) for each Book in readingList check to see if that book was written by `author`; 4) if yes, add that book to `booksByAuthor`; 5) return the `booksByAuthor` list.

Comment: Also, be aware the description of the problem doesn't appear to be OOP - it's more like procedure code wrapped in objects which might be causing some of the confusion.  A more OOP approach would be a class such as `SummerReading` which encapsulates `readingList`, and provides a method such as `List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(String author)`.